# File not found in jar after deployment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have program that throws FileNotFoundException on this statement when the jar is deployed :

```
final var fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("src//main//resources//afp//fop.xconf"));
```

But this works very well locally with intellij.
I looked around a bit and apparently it needs to go through an InputStream but my `FopFactory.newInstance` is waiting a File object as a parameter and not an InputStream.
Could you tell me how to work around this problem please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the jar is depleyed, there is no `src/main/resources` folder. Use `Class.getResource` instead of `File`

Comment: probably because `src` folder isn't deployed! :) (spring-boot!?) try: `@Value("classpath:/afp/fop.xconf") Resource fopConfig` instead (org.springframework.core.io;) ..then you can `FopFactory.newInstance(fopConfig.getFile())`

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html (+ subclasses)

Comment: @xerx593 When I try your suggestion I got this return : 
`[nio-8080-exec-3] e.e.c.FileGenerationController           : java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [afp/fop.xconf] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Users/Guen/Downloads/editique-0.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/afp/fop.xconf`

Comment: i assume best for spring-boot-fop is to: "expand the jar" (which is also best practice for docker images) or at least provide the configs (+fop-resources) externally (since once worked around `new File(...)`, you have the next problem with "baseUrl" and subordinate (conf) resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `File` object points to a file. The resources within a JAR file are not files, so you can not create a `File` object that points to them.

In Spring, one usually would inject a `Resource` instead, and pass that `Resource` to the `FopFactory`. That presumes that the `FopFactory` accepts a `Resource`, or can be changed to accept one.

If that isn't the case, calling code can ask the `Resource` for an `InputStream`, and pass that to the `FopFactory`. If the `FopFactory` is an `org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory`, this can be accomplished by writing `FapFactory.newInstance(baseURI, resource.getInputStream())`.

If the `FopFactory` doesn't accept an `InputStream` either, the only option is to read the `InputStream`, write it to a temporary file, and pass that `File` to the `FopFactory`. But that's really convoluted, and there is nearly always a better option.